# Best practice Firebase search and query

Tags: firebase, flutter, search, google-cloud-firestore

#### Current State

I have a Flutter app which shows me a list of data from Firebase in a list view.

```
  return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return _createRows(
      documentSnapshot.data()['id'],
      documentSnapshot.reference.id,
    );
  }).toList());
```

#### Problem/Question

But the list will get bigger and therefore the loading times will increase but much more important the usage of the read processes will increase exponentially. I also plan to add a search function.

[Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search):

> [...] downloading an entire collection to search for fields
> client-side isn't practical.

Is there a possibility to only query the used data from the `ListView.builder` and to do the search via Firebase?

(One possibility is shown [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/implement-searching-with-firebase-firestore-flutter-de7ebd53c8c9). However, this is not too advantageous for data storage use)
Also, there are a few third party sites, but I couldn't find any free ones in addition, I'm not sure whether the effort to implement in Flutter is worth it. e.g.[elastic](https://www.elastic.co/de/)

I am curious to hear your suggestions

Comment: "Is there a possibility to only query the used data from the ListView.builder and to do the search via Firebase?" Yes there is. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
Thanks for your comment, I'll read it through and see how I adapt it to my circumstances.

Comment: @M123 were you able to adapt the search of the data in the ListView.Builder using Compound Queries?

Comment: @RafaelLemos No, I decided to go another way. I keep my list relatively small and download all the data when I start the app. I then use these locally. This is easier for me in several respects.

Comment: @M123 Could you post you solution as an answer so that the community can refer to it in case they have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to download all the data at the start of the app and then pass it around inside the app, as I have comparatively little data to download and a long stay in the app, it is most worthwhile.

I realised the search with the plugin [TypeAhead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead).